# Deleting files older than X days from different directories using forfiles

Tags: windows, batch, windows-server-2003

I would like to create a batch file that deletes files (only files, not folders neither subfolders) from different directories (100+ different directories) older than 1 day and have this batch run everyday on task scheduler.

I've found this script , but need to adapt it to delete files in multiple directories...
Any help please on how to achieve this? or if this batch will work at all on different directories ?

```
@echo off
:: set folder path
set dump_path=c:\shares\dump

:: set min age of files to delete
set max_days=1

:: remove files from %dump_path%
forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd  /c del /q @path"

:: remove sub directories from %dump_path%
forfiles -p %dump_path% -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

Comment: multiple directories in the sense you want to delete from child directories or they are totally diffrent directories.

Comment: Both , child directories and also different directories....

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to add a `foreach-object` "loop", where you can add a list of folders you want to clean in a text file or array, then run `foreach-object` around your other code.

more info on [foreach-object](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)